# Dia export not satisfactory

Tags: export, dia

I'm using Dia for modeling UML diagrams, but the export to png or eps doesn't make me happy. Many lines aren't straight anymore for certain zoom levels!

Is this a problem of the viewer (in this case gwenview)?
Do I something wrong when I set the lines or is there a function in Dia to prevent this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why do you expect the lines to be straight? what method did you use in  to ensure the straightness of these lines? :)

Comment: I connected the line start and end to the objects until they snap-in. Thereafter I moved the objects until the line seems to be straight. I also checked this with different zoom levels and it was straigth. I'm sure that there is a method to ensure that the line is as straight as a die.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually, what you're looking for is the function to align objects to each other. snap to grid will only work for your purpose in certain situations, like when the connected objects are of equal hight/width, or when the line is connected to the snapped edge.

it's better to align the objects vertically or horizontally. if the line is connected in the middle of the objects, center the alignment. if the line is connected in the right edge of the objects, and they are stacked vertically, use right aligned vertical alignment :)

if i remember correctly, the options for alignment can be found in the object menu. it's definitely in one of the left most menus, in the bottom! i'll update this as soon as i'm at my computer again.

Comment: Yes, this seems to work! In addition to the horizontal alignment you have to select the objects and choose "Align -> Middle". For vertical alignment the option "Align -> Center" achieves that as you described.

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of objects height, and width, if they are connected via arrows ( snap in ) , then one can select the objects ( for example boxes ) that needs to be aligned and press Alt-shift-M. This will straighten all the lines.

Before

[image: Previous]

After Align Middle ( Alt-Shift-M )

[image]